# Coinbase Commerce Webhooks API PHP

Tags: php, api, webhooks, coinbase-api

I'm new to PHP development

I'm trying to learn by implementing some real projects for fun.
So I tried to build a bitcoin app where customers can pay in cryptocurrency.

So I start with Coinbase commerce API

I successfully implement the charge page and everything is working well until I reached the point where I have to deal with WEBHOOKS

I'm following this documentation

```
https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-commerce-php/blob/master/README.md
```

And that's the WEBHOOKs code

```
`<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
use CoinbaseCommerce\Webhook;
/**
 * To run this example please read README.md file
 * Past your Webhook Secret Key from Settings/Webhook section
 * Make sure you don't store your Secret Key in your source code!
 */
$secret = 'SECRET_KEY';
$headerName = 'X-Cc-Webhook-Signature';
$headers = getallheaders();
$signraturHeader = isset($headers[$headerName]) ? $headers[$headerName] : null;
$payload = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
try {
    $event = Webhook::buildEvent($payload, $signraturHeader, $secret);
    http_response_code(200);
    echo sprintf('Successully verified event with id %s and type %s.', $event->id, $event->type);
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo 'Error occured. ' . $exception->getMessage();
}
`
```

When I access to the we hooks URL I got this error

```
Error occured. Invalid payload provided. No JSON object could be decoded
```

Please   I want someone to explain to me this error

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Accessing the URL directly will cause that error because it is expecting JSON to be sent along with the request, coinbase cannot verify the data so returns an exception. Most API have dummy webhooks you can send to test your script ( sometimes you can't verify dummy requests )

Comment: @Adam Gweleg, did you ever figure this out? Im getting it, and usage of the example code is not clear to me at all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are making a GET (No payload data) request to a url that is expecting a POST (Has payload data) request from the web-hook.
To test API's with POST, PUT, GET requests, you can use tools like [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/).
You can build JSON payloads manually and test your endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$headerName = 'x-cc-webhook-signature';

$signraturHeader = isset($headers[$headerName]) ? $headers[$headerName] : null;
```

instead of

```
$headerName = 'X-Cc-Webhook-Signature';

$signraturHeader = isset($headers[$headerName]) ? $headers[$headerName] : null;
```